# Running a Python script with nginx

Tags: python, nginx

I want to run a python script whenever there is a request to nginx. Is there any way I could run python through my nginx conf or If I could add my python script in nginx configuration?

Answer (score -1):

NGINX has support for JavaScript and LUA via modules.

[JavaScript in NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/blog/introduction-nginscript/)
[OpenResty LUA](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#name)

You could use for example the framework Flask and using WSGI within NGINX to front the python application.

[Python Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)

You don't really describe your use-case enough to provide a more specific answer than this.